# Converting this C++ code to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert a straight-forward C code to matlab but I got stuck in something that seemed to be quite clear at first. What's this segment doing? SIZE_N2 = 25, w = 533, h = 800

```
//Init the L matrix. L is a sparse matrix that only contains SIZE_N2 non-zero elements per row.
//We store the L matrix in an array with one row per image pixel and one column per non-zero value. 
//Each array cell accumulates values according to equation 11.
LMatrix = new double* [w*h];
for(i=0; i<w*h; i++){
    LMatrix[i] = new double[SIZE_N2];
    for(j=0; j<SIZE_N2; j++){
        LMatrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Isn't it creating this matrix in Matlab?

> LMatrix = zeros(SIZE_N2, w*h);

When I run the code with this, the matrix goes out of bound on a for loop.

Anyone knows the right implementation of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, you have C++, not C code. (you should change tags)

Comment: I think you don't need the loop, jus do `LMatrix = zeros(SIZE_N2, w*h)`, hope solves the problem, the dimension of the matrix will be `SIZE_N2 x (w*h)`

Comment: But I'm exactly doing that! However, on the next segments of the code, it goes way beyond the size of the matrix size. So, are you saying I did the right job converting it?

Comment: Should use zeros(w*h,SIZE_N2)

Comment: Thanks! I think that was it, doing more tests now to make sure...

Comment: @Yasin One thing: Whatever you do, do never try to implement your own matrix types in Matlab. This requires loads and loads of extra work. In fact the this work may actually force you to recreate all the functions using sparse matrices. As you may know by now there is a sparse matrix type in matlab and this is the only sparse matrix type compatible with all the existing matlab functions. Further, the array used in matlab is called `mxArray` in the mex API and is used for more or less everything. Use mex on functions and let it stay there. Leave the rest up to Matlab. It is what it is made for.

Comment: Thanks Patrik for the input. I'll try my best to rely on Matlab itself for these type of works but sometimes my programming knowledge falls short since I'm more of an artist than programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be helpful to reference the entirety of the [source code](https://github.com/zhaolili/ImageDecomposition/blob/master/ImageDecomp.cpp#L439) (just in case) and some [documentation about it](http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2009/BPD09/index.php) (so we know, for example, what "*equation 11*" is).

Now, if I understand the code correctly, everything (including the loops) could be replaced in MATLAB with the following:

```
LMatrix = sparse([],[],[],w*h,w*h,SIZE_N2*h);
```

Unless you know in advance where the nonzero elements should be, in which case you could just construct the final sparse matrix right there and then, using one of the other syntaxes ([docs1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), [docs2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html)).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the sparse matrix command in Matlab, I'm taking a look at it though I don't know much about sparse matrices that much.

Comment: @Dev-iL, at your version  the total number non-zero elements is SIZE_N2*h and matrix has size [w*h,w*h], but in source C++ code SIZE_N2 number non-zero elements in each rows and we have matrix with size [w*h,SIZE_N2]. Right?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm The description was more helpful for me than the code in this case - it says that "_L is a sparse matrix that only contains SIZE_N2 non-zero elements per row._" => according to my math, __SIZE_N2 per row = SIZE_N2 * h__ nonzero elements. The point here is that in sparse matrices within MATLAB you have the freedom to work (purely for convenience) with the full _size_ of the matrix but only "care" about the nonzero elements. IMHO, it's better not to just translate code but to understand what you're doing and how doing this in MATLAB can benefit you.

Comment: If the matrix has `w*h` rows and `SIZE_N2` entries per row, then the number of nonzeros should be `w*h*SIZE_N2`. You should also mention that using a sparse matrix in this way requires changing the indexing scheme throughout the code in a nontrivial way, which OP probably isn't aware of.

Comment: @cfh - You may very well be right, the names of `w` and `h` are a bit confusing in this context. This needs to be looked at carefully, since MATLAB has an implementation for `sparse` matrices and so the c++ idea may be simplified to account for that. I read somewhere that sometimes it's better to mention that there's a "door" available (i.e. an elegant way to do things) rather than helping someone climb in through the "window" (i.e. ignoring the "why would you do it like that" inner voice).

Comment: @Dev-iL: That's right, there may be a good way to use sparse matrices here, but it's hard to tell without seeing more of the code. In fact, I think this change will lead to a major change in the code -- maybe for the better, but in this case we can't really talk about translating the code anymore, and we should really go back to the mathematical formulation of the algorithm and re-implement it from scratch using a sparse matrix. Everything else is too bug-prone and confusing.

Comment: @cfh - I agree. At this point I'd want the OP to understand that adhering to the c++ code would probably make the code run slower (than it potentially could) since the advanced features of MATLAB aren't being used. In that case they may take the alternative route of [`mex` compilation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html) (which may or may not be easier).

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward translation of your C++ code into MATLAB would be

```
LMatrix = zeros(w*h, SIZE_N2)
```

Note that the first index (number of rows) in the code has size `w*h`, and you swapped them around. This is why you got out of bounds errors, because you indexed the wrong way around.

I'll also mention that C++ uses 0-based indexing, while MATLAB uses 1-based indexing. This *will* trip you up, and you have to be very, very careful to always add 1 to your indices when translating the code.